# How to get URL download in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, modis, download

In the below code I want to download PM image using `getDownloadURL` instead of `Export.image.toDrive()` but returns error. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2ecd8a1ea1788def648f378eb0f7b6b7

```
var pm = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/CAMS/NRT")
.filterDate('2016-01-01','2021-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.select('particulate_matter_d_less_than_25_um_surface')
.mean().clip(table);

print(pm)

var pmDownload = pm.getDownloadURL({
    'image': pm,
    'region': table,
    'filePerBand': 'false',
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are imported as `feature` but `region` argument for `getDownloadURL()` needs a `geometry`. So replace that line with

```
    'region': table.geometry(),
```

[Link to corrected code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3be9ee752e2048c8fbcd7de4dc1a6dc3)

Side note: `getDownloadURL()` can be used for obtaining small images only. For large images (such as the whole district or state), please use `Export.image.toDrive()`.