# Downloading vector file from GEE app

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to download the shapefile of an area in GEE tool/application, It is getting printed in the console but not able to download it using the label. I tried this by using the following answer to the similar question for images, you can check this as well, if required https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344726/221102

```
// Define a panel
var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
  style: {width: '150px'}
});

//title to be shown
var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Brahamaputra Islands',
  style: {'fontSize': '24px'}
});



///////define a variable with button and add the whole process as function in it//////////////////
var load = ui.Button('Load Islands');
load.onClick(function() {
    mainPanel.clear() // .remove() for a single layer and .clear for all panel
    var ed=ee.Date(Date.now());
    var eb=ed.advance(ee.Number(-35),'day')
    
    ///////////////// Dynamic World ////////////////////////
    var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
                 .filterDate(eb, ed)
                 .filterBounds(geometry);
    var img= ee.Image('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1/20230531T042711_20230531T043753_T46RCP');
    // Select label layer
    var classification = dw.select('label');
    var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());
    var water = dwComposite.eq(0);
    
    ////////////////////////////////masking//////////////////////////////
    water=water.selfMask().clip(geometry)
    print(water,"water")

    var bandNames = dwComposite.bandNames();
    print('dwComposite Band names:', bandNames);
    
    var mask = dwComposite.select('label_mode').eq(0);
    var nw = mask.updateMask(dwComposite).clip(geometry)

    // Convert to vectors.
    var vector = nw.reduceToVectors({
      geometry: geometry,
      crs: water.projection(),
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      geometryType: 'polygon',
      eightConnected: false, // it takes4connectedpixels if false
      labelProperty: 'zone',
      reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery()
    });
    
    // Add area property to dissolved features(non water).
    var addArea = function(feature) {
      return feature.set({areaSqKm: feature.geometry().area(1).divide(10e6)});
    };
    var areaAdded = vector.map(addArea);

    ////////////////FILTER AREA/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var Area = areaAdded.filter(ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.gte('areaSqKm', 0.0001),
      ee.Filter.lte('areaSqKm', 3.5)
    ));

    // Export to Drive.
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: areaAdded,
      description: 'non_water_vector',
      folder: 'missingvalues_hold',
      fileFormat: 'SHP',
      maxVertices: 1000000000
    });
    // Get a download URL for the FeatureCollection.
    var downloadUrl = Area.getDownloadURL({
      format: 'CSV',
      filename: 'Islands'
    });
    print('URL for downloading FeatureCollection as CSV', downloadUrl);
    var label= ui.Label
    label.setUrl(downloadUrl);
    label.style().set({shown: true});
  // Add UI elements to the Map.
  var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download viewport', downloadUrl);
  var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
  var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
Map.add(panel);

 });

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//add widgets to the panel
mainPanel.add(title)
mainPanel.add(load);
ui.root.add(mainPanel);

Map.setCenter(91.3021, 26.1741,12)
```

here is the link to my code.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5b79b9e77630be0ffe1d8ebc2acd3da6

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is produced because for downloading a vector layer the **downloadArgs** are completely different for images. It can be corroborated at GEE documentation. So, [following code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/607b349a810654227e3b69252487f430) works as expected. I used my own layer but it also will work with your polygon layer obtained from application of 'reduceToVectors' method.

```
Map.centerObject(table, 10);
Map.addLayer(table, null, 'Vector');

// Define a function to generate a download URL of the image for the
// viewport region. 
function downloadVect() {
  var viewBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds());
  var downloadArgs = {
    format: 'kml',
    filename: 'polygon8'
 };
  var url = ee.FeatureCollection(table).getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);
  urlLabel.setUrl(url);
  urlLabel.style().set({shown: true});
}

// Add UI elements to the Map.
var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download viewport', downloadVect);
var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
Map.add(panel);
```

After running code in above link, I got following result where the downloading link worked without any problem.

[image]

Downloaded kml can also be observed in QGIS in the following picture:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

By the way, it looks that `getDownloadURL()` only can be used for obtaining small files (See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382868/how-to-get-url-download-in-google-earth-engine/383031#383031)).

I modified my former code for obtaining your 'Brahamaputra Islands' (there are 286 features) and it was impossible with `getDownloadURL()`. However, the file could be exported satisfactorily to Drive. Modified code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8654dd9f3115de4d019558c665985941).

Visualized in GEE:

[image]

Visualized in QGIS 3 after exporting to Drive:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code.

1. In this part of the code, you need to call `ui.Label` to get the actual label. So instead of this:

   ```js
   ...
   print('URL for downloading FeatureCollection as CSV', downloadUrl);
   var label= ui.Label
   label.setUrl(downloadUrl);
   ...
   ```

   you need this...

   ```js
   ...
   print('URL for downloading FeatureCollection as CSV', downloadUrl);
   var label= ui.Label() // note here the calling "()"
   label.setUrl(downloadUrl);
   ...
   ```
2. The `onClick` argument of `ui.Button` must be a callable not a string, and the label must have a value, otherwise you wont see it. So change this part:

   ```js
   ...
   print('URL for downloading FeatureCollection as CSV', downloadUrl);
   var label= ui.Label
   label.setUrl(downloadUrl);
   label.style().set({shown: true});
   // Add UI elements to the Map.
   var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download viewport', downloadUrl);
   ...
   ```

   with this:

   ```js
   ...
   print('URL for downloading FeatureCollection as CSV', downloadUrl);
   var label= ui.Label('Download') // call ui.Label constructor to get the actual label, and give it a caption, in this case is "Download"
   label.setUrl(downloadUrl);
   label.style().set({shown: false});
   // Add UI elements to the Map.
   var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download viewport',
       function() {
           panel.add(label);
           label.style().set({shown: true})
       }
   ); // here i provide the function that will be called when the button is clicked, what it does is to add the label to the panel
   var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
   var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
   ...
   ```